# JavaScript/HTML: Unable to access radio-group elements using array notations

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

What I want is:

```
if(document.forms[0].elements[0][1].checked)
```

OR

```
 if(document.forms[0].elements[0].[1].checked)
```

What works is:

```
if(document.forms[0].rad[1].checked)
```

Given:

```
<h3>Who's Bill?</h3>
<input type="radio" value="0" name="rad">Bill Clinton
<input type="radio" value="1" name="rad">Bill Gates
```

Comment: I just don't have to use 'rad' there;  
some standards compel me to use array-format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your second preferred option is simply syntactically wrong. It won't work in any situation, as it defies the rules of the language.

Your first preferred approach is not unreasonable, but consider that what you're asking for is a specific element. Namely, the first element in the form. That element is a SINGLE radio button, not a group of them, so, as much as that syntax might be your preference, it doesn't actually follow what you're looking at in the code.

The way it works is that the form gets an array object named after the radio group name, and that array's children are populated in the order in which your radio buttons actually turn up.

You can also access them as
`document.forms[0].elements["rad"][0];//` (1, 2... etc)
Which may feel nicer to you? I don't know... I'm not sure what you're basing your preferred approach on, so, it's hard to say if this would appeal to you more.

Comment: are you referring to: "Each radio button in a Radio object appears as a separate element in the elements array."?

Answer (score 0):

`elements` contains an array of the all form's elements. It means, when you point to `document.forms[0].elements[0]` you're pointing to the first radio button element. When you use `document.forms[0].rad` instead, you're point to an element with `name` equals to "rad": if multiple elements have the same name, what you get back is an array of elements.

So having something like `document.forms[0].elements[0][1]` it simply wrong: you're trying to access to a property named "1" to the your HTMLInputElement object. In addition, you need to use a name in your HTML code in order to "group" the radios, otherwise they can be selected all together instead of be mutual exclusive.

You can obtain something similar if you really want, building your own function, having something like:

```
var elements = getElements(document.forms[0]);

if (elements[0][1].checked)
```

But I don't see the benefit.